# How can i call the facebook #hashtag images on my site

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

Can Any one tell me the way for facebook #hashtag images to get on my site   site is in wordpress

I am getting image from instagram which are posted there with # tag like #test then all the images with this tag i am geting but i want to know any plugin or core api code by which i able to get the all images which added the # tag #test on my site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **There is currently no public API to retrieve/search hash tags**
>
> You can use the standard Search API but it doesn't specifically search
>   for hashtags (i.e. a search for "#Facebook" will return posts with the
>   word "Facebook" in and not specifically ones with that hash tag).